Spring Boot Fails to Start after First Boot
I am creating a Spring Boot REST CRUD server with some simple data structures. I have a UserMetadata entity, and an Organization entity. The UserMetadata entity has a foreign key to the Organization in a Many-To-One setup.
My issue is that once I start the Spring Boot server, and the tables are created for the entities, if the application ever shuts down, I can never turn it back on because of the following error:
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Attempt to resolve foreign key metadata from JDBC metadata failed to find column mappings for foreign key named [FK_OrganizationToMetadata]
Something about the foreign key association between the two causes issues... If I delete the tables, it boots again fine, but obviously, I can't just delete tables every time I want to restart the application.
Here are all my entities:
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "Organizations-v2")
public class Organization
{
    // This UUID should come from the matching Keycloak Group
    @Id
    @Column(name="id", nullable=false)
    UUID id;
    @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "text")
    String name;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "text")
    String address1;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "text")
    String address2;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "text")
    String stateProvince;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "text")
    String country;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "text")
    String city;
    Integer postalCode;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "text")
    String availableSoftwareProducts;
}

@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "UserMetadata")
public class UserMetadata
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "user-id", nullable = false)
    UUID userID;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "org-id", referencedColumnName = "id", foreignKey=@ForeignKey(name = "FK_OrganizationToMetadata"))
    Organization organization;
    @Column(name = "user-product-args", columnDefinition = "text")
    String userProductArguments;
    @Column(name = "is-org-admin", nullable = false)
    boolean isOrgAdmin;
    
    public Map<String, String> getParsedUserProductArguments()
    {
        if(userProductArguments == null) return Map.of();
        
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        
        for(String str : userProductArguments.split(","))
        {
            String[] keyValue = str.split("=");
            if(keyValue.length == 2) map.put(keyValue[0], keyValue[1]);
        }
        
        return map;
    }
}

Here are screenshots of my databases after they are created:


And here's the full error:
2024-06-28T11:34:40.229-06:00 ERROR 23472 --- [cORE] [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Attempt to resolve foreign key metadata from JDBC metadata failed to find column mappings for foreign key named [FK_OrganizationToMetadata]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1788) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:205) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:952) ~[spring-context-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624) ~[spring-context-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at design.ore.cORE.Main.main(Main.java:37) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Attempt to resolve foreign key metadata from JDBC metadata failed to find column mappings for foreign key named [FK_OrganizationToMetadata]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:421) ~[spring-orm-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:366) ~[spring-orm-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1835) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1784) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Attempt to resolve foreign key metadata from JDBC metadata failed to find column mappings for foreign key named [FK_OrganizationToMetadata]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.AbstractInformationExtractorImpl$ForeignKeyBuilderImpl.build(AbstractInformationExtractorImpl.java:1383) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.AbstractInformationExtractorImpl$ForeignKeyBuilderImpl.build(AbstractInformationExtractorImpl.java:1364) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.AbstractInformationExtractorImpl.getForeignKeys(AbstractInformationExtractorImpl.java:1348) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.TableInformationImpl.foreignKeys(TableInformationImpl.java:97) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.TableInformationImpl.getForeignKeys(TableInformationImpl.java:91) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.equivalentForeignKeyExistsInDatabase(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:484) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.checkForExistingForeignKey(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:476) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applyForeignKeys(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:443) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:268) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:117) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:280) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.lambda$process$5(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:144) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1429) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:141) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryObserverForSchemaExport.sessionFactoryCreated(SessionFactoryObserverForSchemaExport.java:37) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryObserverChain.sessionFactoryCreated(SessionFactoryObserverChain.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:322) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:457) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1506) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75) ~[spring-orm-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    ... 19 common frames omitted

I haven't been able to find anything on the Google to fix this. Thanks in advance for any help!
EDIT: Removing org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl as the physical naming strategy seems to fix the problem, however I'd like to keep the physical naming strategy if possible.

Try removing the hyphens '-' from your column names. This can cause issues in certain databases

The fact that this was the problem makes me unbelievably angry... thank you for the fix, +1
